# For an auxetic solid, what is the relationship between the Shear modulus and the Young's modulus?

Tags: matter

I know that for an isotropic solid, G = Y/2(1+v) but not sure if it is the same for an auxetic solid?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that relation holds for all linearly elastic isotopic materials, regardless of whether Poisson’s ratio is positive.

(In fact, the fact that materials tend to shear in the direction they’re pushed *and* tend to stretch in the direction they’re pulled—positive *G* and *Y*, respectively—places a constraint of $\nu>-1$ on Poisson’s ratio due to this relation.)